# conditional table: only first condition is being executed the other 2 simply remain blank

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner, I need to know what I am doing wrong. I am trying to create a conditional table where after selection of option a number will be generated in last row. but only first condition is being executed the other 2 simply remain blank. This is just a part of code where the rows will be added with different parameters.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SKU generator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Contact Lens</h1>
  <p>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>TYPE</td>
        <td>
          <select id="type">
            <option value="">--Make a choice--</option>
            <option value="full">Full</option>
            <option value="half">Half</option>
            <option value="rimless">Rimless</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p id="demo1"></p>
          <script>
            const select = document.querySelector('select');
            var typ;

            select.onchange = settype;

            function settype() {
              const choice = select.value;

              if (choice === 'full') {
                typ = '0';
              } else if (choice === 'half') {
                typ = '1';
              } else if (choice === 'rimless') {
                typ = '2';
              } else {
                typ = '';
              }
              document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = typ;
            }
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>GENDER</td>
        <td>
          <select id="gender">
            <option value="">--Make a choice--</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="unisex">Unisex</option>
            <option value="kids">Kids</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p id="demo2"></p>
          <script>
            const select = document.querySelector('select');
            var gen;

            select.onchange = setgender;

            function setgender() {
              const choice = select.value;

              if (choice === 'male') {
                gen = '0';
              } else if (choice === 'female') {
                gen = '1';
              } else if (choice2 === 'unisex') {
                gen = '2';
              } else if (choice2 === 'kids') {
                gen = '3';
              } else {
                gen = '';
              }
              document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = gen;
            }
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have used `choice2` in the code, but I think it needs to be `choice`.

Comment: There are a few minor errors: 

`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'select' has already been declared"`, 
`choice2` should be `choice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can mention it like this let const = document.querySelector('#select'); --if id
or let const = document.getElementById('select');

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are finding the select

```
const select = document.querySelector('select');
```

In both scripts, you are referring to the same select.
Try to use id

```
const typeSelect = document.querySelector('#type');
const genderSelect = document.querySelector('#gender');
```

Comment: You are wrong, they exists. Please search for `<select id="type">` and `<select id="gender">`

Answer (score 0):

Off Topic: Why are you doing this with JS in the first place? Why not set these values directly as the `value`-attibute? Like this:

```html
<select id="type">
  <option value="">--Make a choice--</option>
  <option value="0">Full</option>
  <option value="1">Half</option>
  <option value="2">Rimless</option>
</select>
```

```html
<select id="gender">
  <option value="">--Make a choice--</option>
  <option value="0">Male</option>
  <option value="1">Female</option>
  <option value="2">Unisex</option>
  <option value="3">Kids</option>
</select>
```

*I assume the `document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = typ;` lines are more for logging/debugging puposes.*

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getElementById` to fetch the select, as you are assigning id to the select.

```html
<h1>Contact Lens</h1>
          <p>
        <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
        <td>TYPE</td>
        <td> 
          <select id="type">
          <option value="">--Make a choice--</option>
          <option value="full">Full</option>
          <option value="half">Half</option>
          <option value="rimless">Rimless</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p id="demo1"></p>
        <script>
          const select = document.getElementById('type');
          var typ;
          
          select.onchange = settype;
    
          function settype() {
            const choice = select.value;
    
            if(choice === 'full') {
              typ = '0';
            } else if(choice === 'half') {
              typ = '1';
            } else if(choice === 'rimless') {
              typ = '2';
            } else {
              typ = '';
            }
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = typ;
          }
        </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>GENDER</td>
        <td> 
          <select id="gender">
          <option value="">--Make a choice--</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
          <option value="unisex">Unisex</option>
          <option value="kids">Kids</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p id="demo2"></p>
        <script>
          const select1 = document.getElementById('gender');
          var gen;
          
          select1.onchange = setgender;
    
          function setgender() {
            const choice = select1.value;
    
            if(choice === 'male') {
              gen = '0';
            } else if(choice === 'female') {
              gen = '1';
            } else if(choice === 'unisex') {
              gen = '2';
            } else if(choice === 'kids') {
              gen = '3';
            } else {
              gen = '';
            }
            console.log(gen)
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = gen;
          }
        </script>
        </td>
      </tr>

        </table>
          </p>
```